# show array object values inside ajax success section

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

Here am getting the result as follows [image]

Now i want to show that content inside a `select` box with option values so how can we do that..

Here i have written like this

```
 var data = data.user_contacts
 var formoption = "";
 $.each(data, function(v) {
  var val = data[v]
   formoption += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>";
});
 $('#user_contacts').html(formoption);
```

but am getting value as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *keyname* to get required values i.e : `ContactID ,UserID..etc` .

**Demo Code** :

```js
var data = {
  "user_contacts": [{
    "ContactID": 1,
    "UserID": 12,
    "EmailAddress": "A@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "ContactID": 2,
    "UserID": 122,
    "EmailAddress": "A2@gmail.com"
  }]
}
var datas = data.user_contacts
var formoption = "";
$.each(datas, function(v) {
  var val = datas[v]
  //use key to get value 
  formoption += "<option value='" + val.ContactID + "'>" + val.EmailAddress + "</option>";
});
$('#user_contacts').html(formoption);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user_contacts">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will get the val.

```
var data = data.user_contacts
 var formoption = "";
 $.each(data, function(index,val) {
   formoption += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>";
});
 $('#user_contacts').html(formoption);
```